# Monoid associated to $>2$-player Hackenbush

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, universal-algebra, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

*There is some literature on multiplayer combinatorial game theory, but as far as I can tell none of it follows the line of attack below. I'd love a pointer to a similar approach taken in the literature, though!*

---

The assignment of (certain) numbers to (finite) [Red/Blue Hackenbush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackenbush#Variants) boards can be thought of as developing along the following lines:

- We start with the "naive" monoid $N$ of Red/Blue Hackenbush boards with the operation being disjoint union.
- We then assign to each Hackenbush board a "basic type" from $\{$"Red win," "Blue win," or "Second player win"$\}$. The corresponding equivalence relation $\sim$ (= "has the same basic type as") is **not** a congruence on $M$, ...
- ... But it does give rise to one, namely $$A\approx B\quad \iff\quad \forall C(A+C\sim B+C),$$ and the resulting quotient $N/\approx$ is (isomorphic to) the dyadic rationals $\mathbb{Z}[{1\over 2}]$.

Since the "$\sim$-to-$\approx$" trick *always* works *(I was originally only aware of this for cancellative monoids, but Keith Kearnes pointed me to Mal'cev's congruence generation theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631221/when-does-this-construction-always-yield-a-congruence))*, an analogous version of this can be whipped up for $n$-player Hackenbush for any fixed finite $n$ to get a monoid $\mathsf{Hack}_n$. For readability I've put the precise definition of $\mathsf{Hack}_n$ below, but note that as expected we would get $\mathsf{Hack}_2\cong \mathbb{Z}[{1\over 2}]$.

My question is:

> **Question**: What is a more concrete description of $\mathsf{Hack}_n$ in general (or even $\mathsf{Hack}_3$ in particular)?

For example, it *seems* that $\mathsf{Hack}_n$ is never a group for $n>2$, but I haven't been able to prove that.

*(There are a few choices I've made in the definition of the $\mathsf{Hack}_n$s which are not obviously correct; this includes the choice at the outset to focus on Hackenbush specifically as opposed to some other combinatorial game. I would be interested in answers addressing any variation of the construction here, although the specific $\mathsf{Hack}_n$s defined here are what I'm interested in primarily.)*

---

### Definition of $\mathsf{Hack}_n$

For $2\le n<\omega$, define an **$n$-Hackenbush-board** (or "$n$-board" for short) is a tuple $(V,E,S,l)$ where

- $(V,E)$ is a graph with $V\not=\emptyset$,
- $S$ is a nonempty subset of $V$ (the set of "ground vertices") such that every vertex in $V$ is in the same connected component as at least one element of $S$, and
- $l:E\rightarrow[n]$ (where $[n]=\{1,...,n\}$).

Analogously to Red/Blue Hackenbush, a given $n$-board $B$ has *$n$-many* possible games associated to it, one for each choice of first player; after the first move, we follow the obvious pattern $$...\rightarrow n\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow ...\rightarrow n-1\rightarrow n\rightarrow 1\rightarrow ...$$ A move by player $k$ consists of erasing a single $k$-labelled edge, and then erasing all of the (current state of the) board apart from the (new) connected components of the vertices in $S$.

Given such a board $B$, let the **basic type** of $B$ be the set $bt_n(B)$ of pairs $(x,A)$ such that

- $x\in[n]$ is a choice of starting player,
- $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $[n]$ (intuitively a set of players forming a coalition), and
- there are strategies $\pi_a$ for each $a\in A$ such that, in any legal play of $B$ with starting player $x$ in which each $a\in A$ plays according to $\pi_a$, the first player to be unable to move is in $[n]\setminus A$.

*(Intuitively, $(x,A)\in bt(B)$ means "the $A$-coalition can avoid losing if player $x$ starts.")*

We take as our "same basic type" relation $$B_1\sim_n B_2:\equiv bt_n(B_1)=bt_n(B_2),$$

and extract from this the more nuanced equivalence relation

> $B_1\approx_n B_2$ iff for every board $B$ we have $$B_1+B\sim_nB_2+B.$$

Here $+$ denotes the obvious notion of "adding" boards by taking disjoint unions appropriately. Following the above-linked MSE post *(either the argument in my question or Keith Kearnes' much more general argument)* we can show that $\approx_n$ is a congruence on the "naive monoid" $N_n$ of $n$-boards under addition, and so - finally! - we can define the resulting quotient $\mathsf{Hack}_n:=N_n/\approx_n.$

Comment: Before you jump to the general $n$-player Hackenbush, maybe consider the restricted game where the configuration is just a stalk (i.e., $V$ is a linear graph with one extremity as ground), or maybe a finite sum of stalks. For $n=2$ every (bicolor!) configuration is equivalent to a stalk, so the two obvious questions for $n>2$ would be ①what kind of monoid do the stalks give us, and ②is every configuration still equivalent to a stalk?

Comment: What convention are you taking for determining who wins/loses a game with more than two players? For example, Cincotti's "N-player partizan games" and my "An Extension of the Normal Play Convention to N-player Combinatorial Games" follow different conventions.

Comment: @MarkS. By going through $bt$, $\sim$, and $\approx$, I never have to explicitly use such a convention (the question I've asked isn't missing any information). But intuitively, the first player to be unable to move loses, and there is no winner at all - coalitions simply try to avoid containing the losing player.

Comment: Got it, thanks for directing me.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I would definitely be happy for results about that tamer structure.

Comment: If $B$ in the definition of $\approx_n$ could be any finite game and not just a Hackenbush game, then nothing nontrivial would have an inverse. But in $\mathsf{Hack}_n$, I'm not immediately sure whether, say, "an edge for each player connected to the ground" is congruent to the "zero game" with no edges.

Comment: @MarkS. Your first sentence isn't obvious to me (and actually I'd be *more* interested in the corresponding construction for arbitrary finite games, I was looking at Hackenbush in the hopes that things would be easier); can you elaborate? Meanwhile, re: your second sentence, it's definitely **not**: writing "$\langle a_1a_2...\rangle$" for a stack of edges labeled $a_1$, $a_2$, ... from the ground up, we have that $\langle 123\rangle$ is a loss for the coalition $\{1,2\}$ if $1$ opens, but $\langle 123\rangle+\langle1\rangle+\langle2\rangle+\langle3\rangle$ is a win for $\{1,2\}$ if $1$ opens.

Comment: @MarkS. Also you may be interested in [this MSE question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4628676/tricolor-columns-only-hackenbush-boards-must-adding-the-rainbow-board-eventua).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more an extended comment since it doesn't address $\mathsf{Hack}_n$, which I haven't thought much about yet.

Since the basic type is a very complex object, we can define (for all finite games $G$, not just Hackenbush), the (singleton-coalition) outcome $o_n(G)$ to be the subset of $bt_n$ where each $A$ is a singleton. This naturally gives rise to a relation on finite games (Hackenbush or not) analogous to $\sim_n$, given by $o_n(G_1)=o_n(G_2)$. This relation is (a priori in general) *coarser* than $\sim_n$, since coalitions may be able to accomplish different things even if each player working alone cannot. However, for $n=2,3$, it's not coarser.

Note that $o_2(G)$ is the same as $bt_2(G)$. More interestingly, when $n=3$, $(i,\{j\}^\complement)\in bt_3(B)$ means that the players other than player $j$ can force player $j$ to be first unable to move (when player $i$ opens/moves first). This means precisely that $(i,\{j\})\notin bt_3(B)$. This means that $o_3(G)$ determines $bt_3(G)$, and that $o_3(G_1)=o_3(G_2)$ precisely when $G_1\sim_3G_2$ (extending $\sim_3$ to all finite games, say).

We can form an (a priori) *finer* relation than $\approx_3$ by replacing $B$ with an arbitrary finite game: $G_1\approxeq_3G_2$ iff $G_1+G\sim_3G_2+G$ for all finite games $G$, not just Hackenbush games (where $+$ is extended to all finite games in the natural way).

Relatedly, for $n>3$, this splits into $\approxeq^o_n$ and $\approxeq^{bt}_n$, depending on whether $o_n(G_1+G)=o_n(G_2+G)$ or $bt_n(G_1+G)=bt_n(G_2+G)$ (i.e. $\sim_n$) is used. $\approxeq^{bt}_n$ is (a priori) finer than $\approx_n$ since $G$ can be any game. But $\approxeq^o_n$ has a mixture of the two factors: the [equivalence kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_kernel) of $o_n$ being coarser than that for $bt_n$, but $G$ being arbitrary making for a finer relation.

---

In my paper, "An Extension of the Normal Play Convention to $N$-player Combinatorial Games" ([INTEGERS Vol. 20A](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/vol20a.html), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.01375)), "Corollary 4.26" essentially states that (for $n>2$) if $G\approxeq^o_n0$ then $G\cong0$ (where $0$ is the empty game with no available moves). In particular, if $G\approxeq_30$ then $G\cong0$.

Translating into the notation of the question and [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439208/monoid-associated-to-2-player-hackenbush?noredirect=1#comment1134042_439208), here is most of the proof: Let $G$ be a finite game where some player other than player $1$ (let's say player $2$) has a move in $G$. Define $H$ to be a game where player $2$ can only move to $0$ and player $3$ can only move to many copies of $\langle2\rangle+\langle3\rangle+\cdots+\langle n\rangle$ (where "many" means more than the number of possible moves in $G$, say). Then $(2,\{1\})\in bt_n(H)$, but $(2,\{1\})\notin bt_n(G+H)$ since player $2$ can "burn" their first move in $G$, allowing player $3$ to doom player $1$ by playing in $H$. This works identically if player $2$ is replaced with another non-$1$ player other than $n$; and it only requires minor modification to replace player $2$ with player $n$. As a result, if $G\approxeq^o_n0$, then (initially) $G$ must only have moves available for player $1$. But by symmetry, this must be true for the other players as well, so that $G$ must have no moves at all.

To emphasize, since the relationship between $\approxeq^o_n$ and $\approx_n$ is murky, the above result doesn't really say anything about $\mathsf{Hack}_n$ directly. But since $\approxeq^o_n$ is coarser than $\approxeq^{bt}_n$, it *does* say something about "the corresponding construction for arbitrary finite games".

Comment: I've left this answer un-accepted since the question is still open, but this definitely deserves the bounty - thanks a ton!